# How to shorten existing c++ code without an existing database

Tags: c++

I found some (stuipd) repeating If-Else code in a project. Now I'm looking for an idea to shorten and change the code. The problem is, no database or something else is allowed. The values has to be in the code.
Has anybody an idea to shorten following code? My idea was to use a map, but I'm not sure if this will work.

```
if ( a_lFittingOption == FitO_P_BASIC_TT)
{
    if ( dLengthComp > 2000.0 )
        dValue = 1130.0;
    else if ( dLengthComp > 1800.0 )
        dValue = 930.0;
    else if ( dLengthComp > 1450.0 )
        dValue = 780.0;
    else if ( dLengthComp > 870.0 || Null( dLengthComp - 870.0 ))
        dValue = 455.0;
}
else if ( a_lFittingOption == FitO_P_BASIC_TT_RC2 || a_lFittingOption == FitO_P_BASIC_TT_RC1) // 170 mm RC1/RC2
{
    if ( dLengthComp > 1450.0 )
        dValue = 850.0;
    else
        dValue = 455.0;
}
else if ( a_lFittingOption == FitO_P_BASIC_TT_250mm_S)// 170 mm ( S+ Auswahl 250 ) Basic Simply Smart
{
    if ( dLengthComp > 2000.0 )
        dValue = 1130.0;
    else if ( dLengthComp > 1800.0 )
        dValue = 930.0;
    else if ( dLengthComp > 1450.0 )
        dValue = 800.0;
    else if ( dLengthComp > 930.0 || Null( dLengthComp - 930.0 ))
        dValue = 485.0;
}
else if ( a_lFittingOption == FitO_P_BASIC_TT_250mm_S_RC2 || a_lFittingOption == FitO_P_TT_250mm_S_RC1) // 170 mm ( S+ Auswahl 250 ) RC2 Simply Smart
{
    if ( dLengthComp > 2000.0 )
        dValue = 1130.0;
    else if ( dLengthComp > 1800.0 )
        dValue = 930.0;
    else if ( dLengthComp > 1450.0 )
        dValue = 901.0;
    else if ( dLengthComp < 1450.0 || Null( dLengthComp - 1450.0 ))
        dValue = 485.0;
}

return dValue;
```

Thx, for any information and/or ideas. I don't wanna have a complete code, just ideas to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm curious what your Null macro does. If it evaluates to true for negative values, it looks like some of the branches such as else if ( dLengthComp < 1450.0 || Null( dLengthComp - 1450.0 )) can be replaced with just "else"

Comment: This code slice ends several if-else-if chains without else so is the dValue returned uninitialised as result?

Comment: You could make a map from fitting option to a function/lambda that returns the correct d value for the option. Then you can lookup which function to call to get the correct d.
That will remove all the ifs from your code (basically everything in a {} block will be moved to a function)

Comment: FYI: Null is a selfwritten function in the project. The function just checks if dLenghtComp is below 0. And the dValue is initialised with 0.0.

Comment: If `Null()` needs such an explanation, what is its advantage over a simple `<= 0.0` (or `< 0.0`)? (Actually, I believe that the last condition is useless in every case an should be just the `else` branch.)

Comment: Feels like `Null()` is misnamed if it checks for negative values

Comment: For the OP, the question is "why"; what problem are you trying to solve by shortening the code?

Comment: If `Null` just checks for negative values, you're ignoring one value for `dLengthComp` (when it's equal to the smallest limit). If it checks for non-positive values, `dLengthComp > x || Null(dLengthComp - x)` is equivalent to `dLengthComp > x || dLengthComp <= x `, which is trivially true.

Comment: you already seem to have an idea "My idea was to use a map". When not sure if it works you should try and see. Either it works or it doesnt, in which case you could show the non-working code and it would be easier to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will be able to cleanup your code quite a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

double basic_tt(const double dLengthComp)
{
    double dValue{};

    if (dLengthComp > 2000.0)
        dValue = 1130.0;
    else if (dLengthComp > 1800.0)
        dValue = 930.0;
    else if (dLengthComp > 1450.0)
        dValue = 780.0;
    else if (dLengthComp > 870.0) // || Null(dLengthComp - 870.0))
        dValue = 455.0;

    return dValue;
}

const long FitO_P_BASIC_TT = 1;

int main()
{
    std::map<long, std::function<double(const double)>> selected_function
    {
        { FitO_P_BASIC_TT, basic_tt} // extend map here for each strategy
    };

    auto dValue = selected_function[FitO_P_BASIC_TT](3.1);
    

}
```

Comment: I love it for the elegance and hate it for young developers who won't know what the heck is going on :)

Comment: @Gonen If someone wants to I'd be happy to explain :)

Comment: @SchluppIng Are the numbers for strategies (e.g FitO_P_BASIC_TT) numbered sequentially? E.g. could the be used as index into an array? Then the map can be replaced by a static array. Which will perform better.

Comment: @PKramer no, the numbers are not sequentially. It's always a suprise (more or less), which number will come.

Comment: Well if there is a reasonable maximum I started a bit of code that will perform better.
It will create an array from [0..max strategy number +1] instead of a map and do lookups in there which should be faster.
Still not fully constexpr (std::function doesn't have constexpr constructors :( ), link here : https://godbolt.org/z/b4hccT149

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare IFs, and if there is some value that repeat itself, just crop it out of all statements and put it before them as a single IF. But if there is no logic behind it, where is no way to shorten it by some function to save computation time, only define basic/repeated values.

For example, this statement is repeated in every IF statement, so just put it before everything else and comment it as // basic values, or something like that:

```
if ( dLengthComp > 2000.0 )
    dValue = 1130.0;
```

Comment: This assertion about 2000.0 is not true about second if.

Comment: No it is not, so it will be defined later in that IF, either way it will save the computation time in 3 out of 4 statements and removes 3 lines of code from it.

Comment: In most cases, neither the time saving nor the 3 LoC will be useful in their own right; the important aspects are much more likely to be clarity, maintainability, flexibility